Auctex changes when inserting items
I am using AucTex 13.2-1, and I have noticed some changes in the insert-item functionality. Previously, when used C-c C-e, I was prompted for the environment type and, when choosing itemize, the environment was created, including a first item. Using M-<ret>, another item was inserted, without any following brackets. Right now, the first item is not created, which is not a catastrophe, but somehow worse than before. Additionally, M-<ret>  creates an item with curly brackets, and the cursor (in the next example: _) is inside the brackets (i.e. the resulting situation is \item{ _}). I don't like this as it adds some complexity.
To create something equivalent to
\begin{itemize}
\item one
\item two
\item three
\end{itemize}

I usually had to write
C-c C-e <ret> one M-<ret> two M-<ret> three

Now, it's
C-c C-e <ret> M-<ret> one C-e M-<ret> two C-e M-<ret> three

Not much more, but it destroys the writing flow, and I would like to revert to the old behavior. How can I do this?
Edit
Thank you for your reply! I didn't have to upgrade, but after your answer I checked my setup again and found out, that:

The first item is not added when using the beamer document class
The curly brackets are only added when I'm using the bibentry package


I cannot reproduce this with auctex 14.0.3 and so upgrading might be an option here.

Can you add a minimal .tex file to your question exhibiting the issue which works with Emacs started with emacs -Q and the following eval'ed in the scratch buffer:  (progn (setq debug-on-error t) (package-initialize t) (setq TeX-parse-self t) (package-activate 'auctex)) (i.e., put the cursor after the last ) and then hit C-x C-e.  Also do M-x list-load-path-shadows RET to check you don't have any other AUCTeX installation/files sitting on your HD.

Auctex does not start when I am starting emacs as (require 'tex-site) fails...

@Moritz - I presume you've installed AUCTeX from ELPA.  If so, please follow the instructions I gave, otherwise tell us how you installed AUCTeX.  Loading AUCTeX with (require 'tex-site) is deprecated for a long time now, so refrain from doing that.

Originally I used the Debian version. When I'm installing it the way you recommend (from ELPA, and without (require 'tex-site), it works as expected
